# How do I add the BMI calculation to the following code?

Tags: jython, jes

So heres my code below:

```
def inForm():
  name = requestString("What is your name?")
  age = requestInteger("What is your age?")
  height = requestInteger("What is your height?")
  weight = requestInteger("What is your weight?")
  print "Hello", name, "!", "You are", age,"years old!", "Your height  
  is", height, "cm", "and you weigh", weight, "kg"
```

I need to add the BMI calculation to this code, this is my formula, BMI =weight/(height*height)

With these messages displayed depending on BMI:

You are very severely underweight less than 15

Your are severely underweight from 15.0 to 16.0

You are underweight from 16.0 to 18.5

Your weight is normal from 18.5 to 25

You are overweight from 25 to 30

You are moderately obese from 30 to 35

You are severely obese from 35 to 40

You are very severely obese over 40

I can't seem to figure it out, how would i go by this?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of converting from cm to m why don't you use requestNumber for the height and weight. Also, the print statement could be shorter like I have demonstrated below. Also, I use %s %d %r this is called [String Formatting Operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

```
def inForm():
 name = requestString("Please enter your name")
 age = requestInteger("How old are you?")
 height = requestNumber("How tall are you? (Meters)")
 weight = requestNumber("How heavy are you? (Kilograms)")
 bmi = weight/(height*height)

 print "Hello, %s! I see that you are %r years old, %r meters tall, weight %r kgs and your BMI is %d." % (name, age, height, weight, bmi)

 n = bmi
 if n<15:
  print "You are very severely underweight"
 elif 15<=n<=16:
  print "You are severely underweight"
 elif 16<n<=18.5:
  print "You are underweight"
 elif 18.5<n<=25:
  print "Your weight is normal"
 elif 25<n<=30:
  print "You are overweight"
 elif 30<n<=35:
  print "You are moderately obese"
 elif 35<n<=40:
  print "You are severely obese"
 elif n>40:
  print "You are very severely obese"
```

Answer (score 0):

For calculating the bmi, you normally use the height in meters (instead of cm). This means you need to adjust twice for the conversion from cm to m in your formula:

```
bmi = 10000 * weight / (height*height)
print bmi
```

You can use an if-elif-...-else statement for the text part:

```
if bmi < 15:
    message = "very severely underweight"
elif bmi <= 16:
    message = "severely underweight"
# Add more elif parts here...
else:
    message = "very severely obese"

print "You are", message
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't use `height**2`

Comment: I used the formula from the OP, but you're completely right: `height*height` can be replaced by `height**2`.